# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined after form submit

Tags: angular

After a form submit, I have this error in the console :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

The submit method is passed to a dumb component with an output decorator.

Below my code :

**comments.component.ts**

```
export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {
  commentForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() comments: Comment[];
  @Input() source: string;
  @Input() sourceId: string;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private commentService: CommentService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.commentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      text: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmitRequestComment(commentForm: FormGroup) {
    let newComment = new Comment ({
      text: commentForm.value.text as string
    });

    this.commentService.addRequestComment(this.sourceId, newComment);
    this.commentForm.reset();
  }

}
```

**comments.component.html**

```
<div class="component-container">

  [...]

  <app-comments-form
    [commentForm]="commentForm"
    (submit)="onSubmitRequestComment($event)">
  </app-comments-form>

</div>
```

**comments-form.component.ts**

```
export class CommentsFormComponent {
  @Input() commentForm: FormGroup;
  @Output() submit = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();

  constructor() { }

}
```

**comments-form.component.html**

```
<form class="form-container" [formGroup]="commentForm" (ngSubmit)="submit.emit(commentForm)">
  <mat-form-field class="form-field-container">
    <mat-label>
      <i class="far fa-comment-dots"></i> Write your comment...
    </mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="text">
  </mat-form-field>

  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button mat-button color="accent" type="submit">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i> Confirm
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I solve this error message?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you'r **onSubmitRequestComment** function instead of

```
   let newComment = new Comment ({
      text: commentForm.value.text as string
    });
```

Use

```
 let newComment = new Comment ();
  newComment.text = this.commentForm.value.text as string;
```

**Update**

in the function

```
  onSubmitRequestComment(commentForm: FormGroup) {
    let newComment = new Comment ({
      text: commentForm.value.text as string
    });
```

parameter `commentForm` doesn't have value , So `commentForm.value` is null
and of course you cannot call `commentForm.value.text`. 
So It's better to use it like

```
  newComment.text = this.commentForm.value.text as string;
```

and use the public variable (this.commentForm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not working. I still have this error message with these modifications.